# How to properly convert GIS shapefile to a road network?

Tags: gis, anylogic

At the outset, let me just add that I am using Anylogic for the first time, please be understanding.
I have strange problem with conversion GIS .shp file to road network.

I follow the directions in the documentation (I'm trying to do exactly the same as in the documentation example):
https://anylogic.help/markup/converting-roads.html

---

**My GIS map before conversion:**
[image]

**My GIS map after conversion:**
[image]

---

As you can see, Anylogic generated a lot of road networks for me. It should all be in one road network. For this reason, there are no intersections and this is the biggest problem. It does not generate intersections at all, but joints these roads somehow artificially ...

[image]

---

**Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Why no intersections are generated and everything is thrown into separate road networks?**
In the example from the documentation, the intersections have been generated.

---

*I am using Anylogic Professional 30 days trial. Previously I was using the Personal Learning Edition version and there was exactly the same problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. It is caused by the shape file structure. AnyLogic can only interpret what it gets and if the data is not formatted correctly, i.e. road paths are not actually connected in the .shp file, it will create separate networks.

So either adjust the shape file or manually combine the networks, there is no other way, afaik.

Comment: Okay then I will do it manually :< thanks for your help!